# Matplotlib Fullscreen doesn't work with Qt EGLFS

Tags: python-3.x, qt, matplotlib, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

I'm using a raspberry pi 3 with raspbian jessie and I cross compiled Qt 5.6.4 and PyQt5 to make an embedded device, on my app, everything works well, it use the EGLFS driver so there's no X server running (I deactivated it), however, on my app, I have a button that open a matplotlib plot, which is configure to show as fullscreen, and it worked well on the X server (the first test I ran), however, now that I'm using eglfs without x server, the plot appears just in the top left corner of the screen, I will post a picture and my graph code.

[image: Look at the Top-Left corner for the graph]

And my code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as md
from matplotlib.widgets import Button


def graph():

    x = [dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 17, 59), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 18, 4), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 19, 9),
    dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 19, 14), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 20, 19), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 20, 24),
    dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 20, 29), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 21, 34), dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 21, 39),
    dt.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 22, 44)]
    y = [72,68,145,156,184,160,210,230,215,222]
    highest = max(y)
    lowest = min(y)
    xlen = len(x)
    lastdate = xlen - 1
    deltah = dt.timedelta(minutes = 17)
    figfuel, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y, label ='Cb-Ft per hour')
    ax.axhline(highest, color='r', linestyle='--', label='Last 24h max Comsumption')
    ax.text(x[lastdate] + deltah, highest, str(highest), va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=0.5))
    ax.axhline(lowest, color='c', linestyle='--', label='Last 24h min Comsumption')
    ax.text(x[lastdate] + deltah, lowest, str(lowest), va='center', ha="left", bbox=dict(facecolor="w",alpha=0.5))
    #plt.plot(x,y, label='Cb-Ft per hour')
    plt.connect('button_press_event', efecto)

    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    plt.ylabel('Fuel Comsumption (Cb-ft per hour)')
    plt.xlabel('Time (h)')
    plt.title('Fuel Comsumption Chart')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    figManager.window.showFullScreen()
    xformatter = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
    xlocator = md.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,60], interval = 1)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xlocator)
    plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(xformatter)
    #axcut = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
    #axcut = plt.axes([0.885, 0.015, 0.1, 0.075])
    #bcut = Button(axcut, 'Close')
    #bcut.on_clicked(efecto)
    plt.show()

def efecto(event):
    plt.close()
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why this happens?

**EDIT:**

When running the python script, EGLFS tells me it cannot get the screen physical size, I will play with that to see if it changes something

**EDIT 2:**

After running the script with the correct size set on the EGLFS, the same thing happens, so it have nothing to do with that, any help will ve appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, seems like Embedded Qt have problems with the pyplot module, so when I execute the matplotlib script it just doesn't adjust properly to the screen because there is no X server, I tested it and with X server everything works just fine.

Now, if you don't want to use the X server (as me), you need to use the MatPlotlib python widget for the Qt Designer, so you can create a QWidget or a QMainWindow with a plot figure on it, then, you can create a python script to add everything you need to that plot, and it will be as just another Qt window, but with your plot as desired.